# segmentation fault in programm with SIMD commands

Tags: c++, simd

What is wrong here? When I run the program, it says, `Segmentation Fault (Core Dumped)`.
I have used some SIMD commands.

```
float function ( Point p1, Point p2, int dim )
{
      int k;
      float result=0.0;
      float *p3;
      p3 = (float*) malloc (16);
      k=dim%4;

      __m128 *v_p1 = (__m128*)p1.coord;
      __m128 *v_p2 = (__m128*)p2.coord;
      __m128 *v_p3 = (__m128*)p3;

      for (int i=0; i<dim/4; i++){
             *v_p3= _mm_sub_ps(*v_p1,*v_p2);
      }
      for(int i=0; i<dim; i++){
             result+=p3[i];
      }
      return(result);
}
```

Comment: My guess is that `_mm_sub_ps` requires `16 byte` aligned data and `p1.coord`, `p2.coord` and `p3` are not properly aligned. So if you assign to `__m128` variables by value which should be correctly aligned and use those I bet the problem goes away.

Comment: Try to debug with **gdb**.

Comment: Not concerning fault: It seems that the first cycle executes operation with the same data again and again

Answer (score 0):

As the comment says, when working with SIMD intrinsics, the data in memory must be aligned (in this particular case, 16 byte aligned), in case you are in a UNIX system try to allocate the data with `posix_memalign()`:

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/posix_memalign.html

Answer (score 0):

Any of the `SIMD _ps` instructions are going to require `16` byte aligned data. From what I can tell at least `p3` is not properly aligned and so you will most definitely get a `seg fault` if you do not use properly aligned data. I can not run this code myself but if you assign to the `__m128` variables by value you should be okay since they should properly aligned:

```
  __m128 v_p1 = _mm_set_ps( ... ); // not sure of the argument 
  __m128 v_p2 = _mm_set_ps( ... ); // not sure of the argument 
  __m128 v_p3 = _mm_set_ps1(p3) ;
```